# Collectors.toMap IllegalStateException: Duplicate key when no duplication is possible

Tags: java, exception, java-stream

I keep hitting this error and I'm not able to make sense of it, because it complains about a value that is **present exactly once**.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#13236
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1245)
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at <my code>
```

This is the original code:

```
reader.lines().filter(line -> line.startsWith(TAG_MAPPED_NODE)).map(line -> {
    final String[] splitted = line.split(" ");
    if (splitted.length != 3)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected line: " + line);
    return splitted;(splitted[1],splitted[2]);
}).collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t[1], t -> t[2]));
```

However, the value it complains about exists exactly once. Validation code:

```
List<String> usefulLines =
    reader.lines().filter(line -> line.startsWith(TAG_MAPPED_NODE)).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> trouble =
    usefulLines.stream().filter(line -> line.contains("wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#13236")).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Trouble size: " + trouble.size());
return usefulLines.stream().map(line -> {
    final String[] splitted = line.split(" ");
    if (splitted.length != 3)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected line: " + line);
    return splitted;
}).collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t[1], t -> t[2]));
```

And the output is: `Trouble size: 1`

So, there is only one entry that has this value (and, I must add, I'm storing it in the Value side of the Map, *not* the Key)

System configuration:

- Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_72"
- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1
- OS: Fedora 22 64 bit

So how in the world am I getting that exception? This looks like a JDK bug to me - anybody seeing something I did wrong?

Comment: `return splitted;(splitted[1],splitted[2]);` is this legal?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. One extremely useful thing you could do here is find out exactly what's in `reader.lines()`, save it to a text document or something and post it here so we actually know what your data is. Also please post the *entire stack trace of the exception*, not just the class name and message.

Comment: @YassinHajaj An object with a `lines()` method which returns a `Stream<String>`, I suppose.

Comment: After investigating, I narrowed it down to the minimal data that would create the issue. The key is duplicated, but what is shown in the error is a value. This issue is well-known already (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892l) and it should've been fixed, but it looks like the fix has not made it in recent OpenJDK builds.

Comment: well according to the bug tracker, the fix version is 9, so I guess it won't be fixed in java 8

Comment: @malaverdiere: Don't be afraid to post that as an answer and accept it...might help future Googlers.

Comment: Btw in my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library this issue is fixed: `StreamEx.ofLines(reader).filter(...).map(...).toMap(t -> t[1], t -> t[2])` would throw an exception containing the key and both duplicate values.

Comment: I also got this weird "bug" today: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 0.7868354` But I'm pretty sure my keys are string labels, the "duplicate" "key" that error mentioned is actually the values (which are floats) and I don't care if the values are duplicates. The bug page @malaverdiere mentioned no longer exists. But this is very critical bug in common data structure library!!! :( Now I have zero confidence in Collectors.toMap!!

Comment: @HendyIrawan I'm not sure I would classify a bug where the code behaves correctly but has bad error messaging as "very critical".  Note that the duplicate key check itself is correct; it's just the error messaging that's incorrect.  But it is a source of confusion, and was right to have been fixed.  Also, that bug page still works for me, so maybe it was temporarily down when you checked?

Comment: @M.Justin It's _not_ a duplicate key. It's duplicate _value_, which should be allowed. That's the bug, which is fixed in Java 9 (see answer below). If it wasn't a bug, they wouldn't fix it.

Comment: @HendyIrawan No, it _is_ a duplicate key, not a duplicate value.  Note the title of the bug ("Incorrect message in Exception thrown by Collectors.toMap(Function,Function)") and the bug description text ("Clearly, the value being printed is not the key, but rather one of two values for which there is a key collision.").  The problem here is that two keys are duplicates, but the error messaging is incorrectly listing the value mapped to the key as the duplicate, not the key itself as the duplicate.  And I never claimed it wasn't a bug.

Comment: @M.Justin I stand corrected. You're right, it's a misprinted duplicate key which then causes confusion. Thankfully it's been fixed. Hopefully more people upgrade to Java 11 and beyond so this bug won't surface again.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to replace buggy `Collectors.toMap()` with Guava's [`ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#toImmutableMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-). Yay!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments on the question, the confusion here is due to a bug in Java 8 ([JDK-8040892l](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892l)).  When there is a duplicate key, the value is printed out as being the duplicate, rather than the key.

There therefore is in fact a duplicate key, but it is not the value shown in the exception message.  In this specific case, whatever key maps to "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#13236" is the one that is duplicated.

This bug was fixed starting in Java 9.